# Can Circle CI push to github if tests pass?

Tags: node.js, github, continuous-integration, circleci

I'm trying to set up a continuous integration system where I can push code to CircleCI and CircleCI will merge with master, run the tests, and push to master ONLY IF TESTS PASS! Is there a way to accomplish this with CircleCI or any other CI solution that's free for a single private GitHub repo?

Answer (score 0):

I'm from CircleCI. It seems possible to do this on CircleCI. You can do this by putting commands in deployment section of circle.yml which is executed only when tests passed.

If you need more details, you can ask the question in our support.

Thanks,
Kim

Comment: Sure, I'll try that and see if there are any problems.

Comment: I get a failure because the key is read-only. is there something I can do?

Comment: Hi, we have a [doc](https://circleci.com/docs/adding-read-write-deployment-key) for this. BTW, we now have a better place to ask questions about CircleCI. Checkout our [community forum](https://discuss.circleci.com/) !

Comment: @kimh the link does not work (content no found). Can you show us an updated link perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

ghr https://github.com/tcnksm/ghr is a simple tool to create GitHub Release and upload artifacts by only one command.

```
- ghr -t $GITHUB_TOKEN -u $CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME -r $CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME v1.0.$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS/ || true
```

Please note to mention CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS in the environment variables.